# How to get metadata(Column Value) in SharePoint from powershell

Tags: powershell, file, sharepoint, metadata, sharepoint-online

I am trying to get the metadata(column values) for each file in powershell (refer image and code till now)
While running the below code name i am getting, but other values if i try like only the name is priniting..

```html
$File.Name + $File.FieldValues.Hash | Format-Table
```

is there any way to get all the values from the columns for every file in the folder ? -

**Code Till Now** -

```html
   Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
#Get Connection to the url , #Connect-PnPOnline $URL 
Connect-PnPOnline "Some SharePoint Url" -UseWebLogin

$SharePointFolderPath = "Some folder in Shared Documents"
$FolderItems = Get-PnPFolderItem -ItemType file -Recursive -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $fileURL

foreach($file in $FolderItems){

#$File = Get-PnPFile -Url $fileURL -AsListItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue #by using this and giving the exact path/Filename.txt the values are coming for only that file but not for all the files.. but not with get folder items also.
$File.Name #Only name is coming 
$File.Hash #Hash column is custom created by myself but its not returning anything other than null,the actual value should be returned.
#$File
}
```

[ScreenShot for the metadata column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJGdi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I answered in your another question, you could try this for the `hash` column

```
 $FolderItems = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderURL -ItemType File -Recursive
 ForEach($File in $FolderItems){
    $File.Name
    $fileURL=$FolderURL+"/"+$File.Name
    $fileItem=get-pnpfile $fileURL -AsListItem
    $fileItem['Hash']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://evotec.xyz/getting-file-metadata-with-powershell-similar-to-what-windows-explorer-provides/) that might help. Below is a script I was playing with while learning about Metadata using the Get-FileMetaData function. It's in the PowerShell Gallery and I think it is safe to run.

First run: `Install-Module -Name PSSharedGoods`
Example from the author:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -Force | Get-FileMetaData -Signature | Out-HtmlView -ScrollX -Filtering -AllProperties
```

Then this is how I was using their function:

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem
foreach($File in $folder) {
$fileMetaProperties = @($(Get-FileMetaData $File | Select-Object -Property Name,Title))
$a = $fileMetaProperties.Name
$b = $fileMetaProperties.Title
Write-Output "$a and $b"
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Actually i want to get the metadata from SharePoint folder not from the local folder . Is there anyway ?